# Permission denied (publickey) error to clone repo in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hi I have added same ssh keys to Compute Engine>MetaData>SSh keys, here I have configured my ssh keys but still unable to clone repo to google cloud platform.

Comment: did you add the key to the repo?

Comment: yes ofcourse, I configured same public key to my bitbucket repo and google cloud platform.

Comment: Could you post an error traceback?

Comment: Are you trying to clone the repo to cloud repositories or clone the repo to your instance?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70646008/442512