# Google Cloud Source Repositories: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I have a source repository setup in a project. I have my main admin user and I created a second user (did try a service account at first) and gave that user "Project Owner" access on the project with the source repo.

I created an SSH key on my local machine by running: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -C "user@domain.com" -f "mysshfile"`

I created a  config file in my .ssh folder:

```
Host source.developers.google.com
 HostName source.developers.google.com
 Port 2022
 IdentityFile /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/mysshfile
```

I copied the contents of my mysshfile.pub and registered it with Cloud repo SSH keys.

When git clone as the my second user it fails with the error message of: **Permission denied (publickey)**. When I git clone as my main admin user, it works.

So I ran the ssh command with verbose to check: `ssh -p 2022 -l admin@domain.com -v source.developers.google.com`, I get:

........

```
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/mysshfile RSA SHA256:U+XREDACTED explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/xxxxxx/.ssh/mysshfile RSA SHA256:U+XREDACTED explicit
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to source.developers.google.com ([74.125.197.82]:2022).
```

When I run the same command as my test user: `ssh -p 2022 -l test@domain.com -v source.developers.google.com`, I get:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/mysshfile RSA SHA256:U+XJREDACTED explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
test@domain@source.developers.google.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I can't figure out why the git clone using ssh works for one user (the one I don't even want) and not another?

Comment: Authentication is `username` plus `public key`. You need to register the public key in that user's GCP account. Authenticate as the other user and then go to this page: https://source.cloud.google.com/user/ssh_keys

Comment: Thanks John, that was it. It didn't click with me that the SSH key registration was user specific vs global. Do you know if there is a way for a service account to register an SSH key?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/70646008/442512 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line into your config file:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

So it should now be:

```
Host source.developers.google.com
 HostName source.developers.google.com
 Port 2022
 IdentityFile /Users/XXXXX/.ssh/mysshfile
 PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

On the verbose mode you will see the following lines:

```
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

It means that `ssh-rsa` algorithm was disabled. Which can be re-enabled as explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html#SSHRSAkeyrejectedwithmessage%22nomutualsignaturealgorithm%22-Workaroundforre-enablingRSA).