# Clone cloud source repository using vscode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

Can't clone cloud source repo, I added the ssh public key and followed that link which I thought having the same scenarios that I had
https://ashraful.la/posts/2020-02-21-vscode-with-google-cloud-source-repository/

But still get the error of Permission denied (publickey)
Any help with that?!
It should have been a straight forward move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#ssh),

> Cloud Source Repositories lets you use SSH public key authentication to access hosted repositories. In this scenario, you first generate a key pair on the local system from which you want to access the repository. Then you [register the public key](https://source.cloud.google.com/user/ssh_keys) with Google Cloud. If you already have an SSH key pair on your system, you can re-use those keys for authentication. You can register up to 20 public keys per Google Account.

There are three SSH key types supported by Cloud Source Repositories:

- RSA (only for keys with more than 2048 bits)
- ECDSA
- ED25519

You may also check this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961649/get-permission-denied-publickey-for-git-push-to-google-cloud-source-repository/70646008#70646008).